# How do I combine two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to find the results of this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  ColumnX in (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnX FROM Table2 
                   UNION
                   SELECT DISTINCT ColumnY FROM Table2)
```

That also filters the results by DateAddedToMarket, a column in Table1 using this query:

```
         DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND      DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
ORDER BY DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Table1 
WHERE  ColumnX in (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnX FROM Table2 
                   UNION
                   SELECT DISTINCT ColumnY FROM Table2) 
AND    DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
ORDER BY DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

I received the proper dates but also received results outside of values I wanted to match from Table2.

```
+--------+--------------+
|ColumnX |    ColumnY   |
+--------+--------------+
| 872510 |       879962 |
| 872514 |       879963 |
| 872511 |              |
| 872515 |              |
| 872512 |              |
| 879529 |              |
| 872513 |              |
| 879530 |              |
| 879959 |              |
| 879960 |              |
| 879961 |              |
+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: "I received the proper dates but also received results outside of values I wanted to match from Table2. ", but the only filter you have is for the dates... so which values are you referring to?

Comment: @LearnByReading Updated, showing Table2.

Answer (score 1):

This query will not work if DateAddedToMarket is intended to be searched in the subquery table (which is Table 2 in this case).

In here, the main query obtains the data from Table1 WHERE ColumnX is found in Table 2. So the date filter (DateAddedToMarket ) does not apply to this. It is just grabbing EVERYTHING that is given to it by Table1 through ColumnX...

In practice, if you are trying to search within Table 2, then this query would not achieve this. You'd need to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnX in (

SELECT DISTINCT ColumnX FROM Table2 WHERE DateAddedToMarket ... UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ColumnY FROM Table2 WHERE DateAddedToMarket ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The select clauses "IN" function is terribly inefficient unless the query optimizer can make it a join. Change you "in(... union ...)" clause and join the tables. Then add your filters in the where clause**s** and Union two nearly identical Selects.

```
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnX
where Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
UNION
SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 on Table1.ColumnX = Table2.ColumnY
where    Table1.DateAddedToMarket >= '2018-01-01' 
AND    Table1.DateAddedToMarket < '2018-02-01' 
ORDER BY Table1.DateAddedToMarket DESC
```

Comment: It seems to be giving me values that are not in Table2. I wonder why this is?

Comment: It should not, but I had a typo.  The first "and" in each join should be "where". Two of them.  You could also run each of the unioned queries by themselves and see what you get.